# ChartJS align axis label to the top

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs

Is there a way in [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/) / [`react-chartjs-2`](https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2) to align the Y-Axis title to the top of the axis instead of the default vertical alignment?

In other words, instead of this:
[image]

I want this:
[image]

My basic configuration for the Y-axis is as follows:

```
yAxes: [
  {
    scaleLabel: {
      display: true,
      labelString: '$ USD'
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is built-in support for this requirement in Chart.js however you can fill the `ctx` with any value from the code shown below. Please adjust the `xOffset` and `yOffset` value as per your need. Fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/Lzo5g01n/8/

```
animation: {
      duration: 1,
      onComplete: function() {
        var controller = this.chart.controller;
        var chart = controller.chart;
        var yAxis = controller.scales['y-axis-0'];
        var xOffset = chart.width - (chart.width - 5);
        var yOffset = chart.height - (chart.height - 18);
        ctx.fillText('$USD', xOffset, yOffset);
      }
    }
```

With the above code there is one issue that the label goes off on hovering over the bar.

This new code may help to resolve the issue -> http://jsfiddle.net/moz73qep/3/

```
var myBarExtend = Chart.controllers.bar.prototype.draw;

Chart.helpers.extend(Chart.controllers.bar.prototype, {
    draw: function () {
      myBarExtend.apply(this, arguments);   
      var controller = this.chart.controller;
        var chart = controller.chart;
        var yAxis = controller.scales['y-axis-0'];
        var xOffset = chart.width - (chart.width - 5);
        var yOffset = chart.height - (chart.height - 18);
        ctx.fillText('$USD', xOffset, yOffset);
    } });
```

Comment: This works almost well, but when you click on some bar (for example), the axis label then kind of "flashes" (I guess there is some rerendering going on). Would you have a solution for that?

Comment: @MilanVlach Little tricky to understand but this fiddle can fulfill your need -> http://jsfiddle.net/moz73qep/3/